# How to change the binding hostname in WSDL when use the WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

When I Create Proxy Service use the Custom Proxy 
I want to change the hostname from `"http://localhost:8280/services/AppointWebServiceProxy.AppointWebServiceProxyHttpSoap11Endpoint"` to 
`"http://10.10.11.176:8280/services/AppointWebServiceProxy.AppointWebServiceProxyHttpSoap11Endpoint"`
 in the binding from WSDL:

```
 <wsdl:port name="AppointWebServiceProxyHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="tns:AppointWebServiceProxySoap11Binding">
 <soap:address location="http://localhost:8280/services/AppointWebServiceProxy.AppointWebServiceProxyHttpSoap11Endpoint"/> 
 </wsdl:port>
```

I  have change the `<HostName>10.10.11.176</HostName>` in the carbon.xml and
 change the `<parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">10.10.11.176</parameter>`  in the axis2.xml
 but all of that are not work,how coule I do ?

Answer (score 4):

To change the url your service is published, you have to edit the parameter

```
<parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">http://hostname os IP address</parameter>
```

to the value you want at the axis2.xml file, section Transport In (Listeners)

Regards